# Links in footer section

Tags: php, links, footer

I'm currently trying to the Wordpress page of a friend.

He asked me that the footer section of the site shall contain to links with the names "AGB" and "Impressum" with lead to new tabs with the content.

At the moment the code looks like this but it has 2 problems:
- The fonts of the 2 words are different
- I don't know where to add the link address

```
echo '<div class="zerif-copyright-box"><a class="zerif-copyright" href="http://themeisle.com/themes/zerif-lite/"'.$attribut_new_tab.' rel="nofollow"></a>'.__('AGB','zerif-lite').'<a class="zerif-copyright" "'.$attribut_new_tab.' rel="nofollow"> Impressum</a></div>';

echo '</div>';
```

Hope you can help me :)

Cheers,
Domi

Answer (score 0):

I have improved your code to a new version as i have found that you have used text "AGB" out of anchor tag

**Updated Code**

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<div class="zerif-copyright-box">';
$html .= '<a class="zerif-copyright" href="http://themeisle.com/themes/zerif-lite/"'.$attribut_new_tab.' rel="nofollow">'.__('AGB','zerif-lite').'</a>';
$html .= '<a class="zerif-copyright" href="" "'.$attribut_new_tab.' rel="nofollow"> Impressum</a>';
$html .= '</div>';

$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Hope this helps!